# How to draw alpha on an image / setting pixels invisible - on fingertouch

Tags: android

I want to create a little scratch game. The problem is, that I can't figure out how to erase pixels from an image in android (like the eraser in gimp / photoshop).

The image is an .png with alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

AIUI, drawing operations on a canvas blend a transparent pixel with the prior value of the pixel. This is by default, and you can see it by setting a canvas to black and drawing a fully transparent shape onto it, and then drawing the underlying bitmap over an image of another canvas (result: a fully black canvas), or by setting a canvas to a partially transparent color and, drawing a shape of another partially transparent color, and then drawing this over an image (result: the original image is tinted by the first color, outside the shape; within the shape, it's tinted by *both* transparent colors).  I don't know the blending method used by default, and looking through the docs just makes me wish I knew what book to buy so I can understand how to use what's available.

So I would set pixels to transparent by setting them 'directly', with Bitmap methods, rather than with canvas operations.  Although if you need to punch a transparent shape into an overlay, you can draw the shape with a solid non-transparent color, and *then* manipulate the bitmap directly, mapping this color to the transparent color.

[Bitmap docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).  Prefer getPixels() and setPixels() to a method-call per pixel.

EDIT: ...er, did I misunderstand?  You want to 'erase' pixels as in a paint program?  Then just draw whatever the background color is.  There's no erasure involved.

Comment: Thank you for the response: I cant draw the background color because there's an background image :)

Comment: Then get pixels from the background image, or make them transparent in an overlay, or otherwise manage layers in your view.  What you should do depends on what you're actually wanting to do.

Comment: I want to add translucent pixels to my image. I've got a background and a single image above. When a touch occurs, something should happen, to draw translucent pixels "in" the image above the background. Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Then set the pixels to transparent in your foreground image.  As I describe in my answer, canvas operations with a transparent paint won't have the desired effect; use getPixels/setPixels on the bitmap.

Comment: Is it possible to work with the Porter-Duff Modes (XFerMode)?